# What counts as a "hit" for the new affix on Broken Promises?

Tags: diablo-iii

Patch 2.2 re-worked some legendary items, among them the Broken Promises ring.  It's new affix states:

> After 5 consecutive non-critical hits, your chance to critically hit is increased to 100% for 3 seconds.

So, what counts as a hit?  I know regular primary attacks will. But do gem procs, such as Miranae's smite?  The Wreath of Lightning's AoE zapping?  Pet attacks?  Do AoE attacks count only once, or once per monster hit?  What about sustained skills, such as Sweeping Wind?

Way of the Hundred Fists also has an attack that does multiple hits.  You can easily see it calculate crits separately per hit, so do those count as separate hits for the purposes of this affix?

I can see a non-crit build, buffed with as much attack speed as you can stack, keeping this proc up almost 100% of the time.

Comment: I am sure there is an internal cooldown for this proc, if not now, Blizz will add it later

Comment: Any internal cooldown on this item would dramatically reduce it's effectiveness.  I don't think Blizz will do that, as they're trying to offer different solutions.  This ring would negate the need for critical hit chance on items, which is one of the goals they've been going for; lower the need for the trifecta.  Internal cooldowns would just push people back to the trifecta.

Comment: Sweeping wind hits are counted? That would be a little broken but fun.

Comment: Yea but without any internal cooldown this ring would be OP

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau I have no idea if they are or not.  I'm preeeeeetty sure it ticks off of your IAS, but I don't know how it will interact with this proc.  If it does, I can see things getting awfully silly.

Comment: @Huangism Depends on what counts as a hit.  If it's just regular primary attacks, then it'll take at least a second and change to proc it, which will give you somewhere around a 70% crit rate, and that's only if you focus on IAS to the exclusion of all else.  More likely, most people will be around a 50% uptime, which you can get with crit chance all by itself.  An internal cooldown does nothing but nerf the utility of this ring.

Comment: Well, an internal cooldown for basically anything does "nerf" that thing, but still there are lots of item effects with internal cooldowns. This may be a subtle indication that Blizzard does not want to make players as powerful as they demand to be.

Comment: There's no internal cooldown, but it can't proc again while you have the bonus (unlike Flying Dragon); so you get the bonus for 3 seconds, then the bonus ends, then it starts counting to 5 again. This seems redundant because during the buff you're at 100% crit, but there are some skill that can't crit, so this forces a minor "cooldown".

Answer (score 2):

I did some testing earlier today and found there does seem to be a bit of an internal cooldown. After 3-4 seconds of your crit chance buff going down, you can repeat the process of activating the ring.

I play monk and tried with a few spirit generators and none of them seemed to be a clear cut best choice, although I do need to keep testing. To answer your question about hundred fists (and each spirit generator), they are all combos with 3 hits. So even though it shows a lot of little punches, it only counts as 3 hits per sequence. Hundred fists is cool though, because your ring buff activates right before the 3rd part of your 2nd sequence which is a flurry of little punches. As long as you didn't crit in the middle of it, that is.

Bonus: I did a little more research and it seems that only skills performed by you will count towards the ring proc, so pets/item specials probably won't affect it. But sweeping wind does proc it...and it can't crit ;)